# OAuth for a Single Allowed User via API Gateway and Lambda

Tags: oauth, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm building a site and API for my own personal purposes, and I figured I'd use API Gateway and Lambda functions to keep costs down.

I need a way to authenticate, and using my Google or GitHub account with OAuth seems to be a good idea.

However, since:

1. There's only going to be one user for the foreseeable: me.
2. I'd like to be able to build command-line tools around these APIs I'm building.

I'm not sure that OAuth is the right approach. Is there a way to limit who can sign up/sign in with OAuth as an authentication backend? Additionally, should I add more allowed users, is it easy to build authorization around an OAuth based system?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easier ways to auth, is to use 
[Cognito User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-cognito-user-pools.html). Currently, the Cognito User Pool free tier includes 50,000 monthly active users. You can choose to "Admin Confirm" your users to prevent unwanted users from signing up. See more info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html).

The guide for integrating Cognito User Pools with API Gateway is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)